# What does the domain in vm host TCP/IP stack DNS config do?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vcenter

We are pulling an Active Directory server out and modifying DNS settings on all systems. Attempting to update DNS list on a vm host results in a validation error that the domain value is not filled. How could this have been setup originally without, what does it do and is there any harm in adding our domain?

Answer (score 1):

It's for your [Fully-Qualified Domain Name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) (FQDN) for the host.

Ideally, the domain name of the ESXi host is defined. You don't have to, but it's generally helpful if the rest of your network has internal DNS.

Comment: I was about to answer something very similar but I'd be stronger about it in that you pretty much HAVE to have working forward and reverse DNS for your vCenter and hosts attached to it - things can go very weird it you don't.

Comment: And if you are not in a domain environment, what should you put here?